# Hilbert $C^*$-module over approximately finite $C^*$-algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Is there a construction of a Hilbert c*-module over an approximately finite c*-algebra using Hilbert c*-modules over finite algebras? How do we get a Hilbert c*-module over an inductive limit of such finite algebras?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issue here. If $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq \cdots$ is an increasing sequence of C*-algebras and $E_1 \subseteq E_2 \subseteq \cdots$ with $E_n$ a Hilbert module over $A_n$ (compatibly), then the completion of $\bigcup E_n$ is a Hilbert module over the completion of $\bigcup A_n$ in the obvious way. That's a simple exercise.